# why is awk pattern match not returning results?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

create a file (x) with below 1 line:

```
{"dagId":"blashj","execDate":"20190426","status":"running","isActive":true}
```

-->  returns desired value ---> true

```
cat x | sed -e 's/[{}"]/''/g' | awk -v RS=',' -F: '/^\isActive/ {print $0}'
```

-->  why does this not return a value??  desired value ---> running

```
cat x | sed -e 's/[{}"]/''/g' | awk -v RS=',' -F: '/^\status/ {print $0}'
```

env is RHEL7.4, GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: Why not use `jq` to parse json data?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `i` and `s` chars in your regexps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be because `\s` doesn't match?

Comment: my understanding is /^\isActive/ will look for line starting with isActive , and it returns so what is different about the other pattern?

Comment: `/^\status/` says "look for a line that begins with a space (`\s`) followed by the string `tatus`." c.f. [the guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html) for a list of escape sequences.

Comment: it is working as i expect on RHEL5 box but on RHEL7 behavior must have changed

Comment: there is no line starting with tatus

Comment: `\s` as an escape sequence matching whitespace is specific to gawk. Probably you were previously running non-gnu awk, where `\s` would match an `s`, but in your new system you are using gnu awk.
You can add `--traditional` and if it starts working you'll know why. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators

Comment: old awk was GNU Awk 3.1.7, you are right --traditional on new awk works!

Comment: @tooptoop4 I feel like you're missing the real point which is - don't do that! If you simply don't escape the `s` when you don't want it to mean `[:space:]` then you don't have to worry about which awk version you're executing or what flags to pass it. If you want the character `s` in a regexp then just write `s`, not `\s`. wrt `/^\isActive/ will look for line starting with isActive` - well, yeah but so will `/^isActive/` since `\i` means the same as `i` (unless someone comes up with an awk version or flag some day where `\i` gets a special meaning!)

Answer (score 1):

I would wholeheartedly endorse `jq` which should be available on your platform :

```
jq -r '"isActive:"+(.isActive | tostring)' file
```

If you just need that value of an object attribute, it can be as simple as

```
jq -r '.status'  file
```

The `-r` or `--raw-output`  writes the string directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes

<sub>See [jq is sed for json](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/jq-is-sed-for-json). Using the right tool saves time.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you don't have access to `jq` at work, I would use a regular expression as the `awk` Record Separator.

```
$ awk -F: -v RS='[{},]' '/"isActive"/{print $2}' x
true

$ awk -F: -v RS='[{},]' '/"status"/{print $2}' x
"running"
```